# ansible: why is the file module skipping?

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible 1.1 playbook where I do something like this:

```
- name: copy files
  sudo: True                                                                                                             
  shell: cp /from/* /to/

- name: change owner
  sudo: True
  file: path=$item owner=newuser group=newgroup
  with_fileglob: /to/*
```

The second task, "change owner" is always skipping. can anyone help me finding out why? is the file module skipping because the files exist? I'm stuck :)

Comment: Never knew if it allows $item ...I thought it was {{ item }}

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [documentation](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/release1.1/docsite/rst/playbooks2.rst#lookup-plugins---accessing-outside-data):

> Remember lookup plugins are run on the "controlling" machine:

`with_fileglob` is a lookup plugin, so it looks for files on the local server, the one you are running ansible-playbook from.

Here is what you can do:

```
- name: list files 
  action: command ls -1 /to/* 
  register: dumpfiles 

- name: change ownership 
  action: file path=$item owner=newuser group=newgroup
  with_items: ${dumpfiles.stdout_lines}
```

Comment: that makes so much sense now that you say it. BTW, I solved this by using [shell: chown -R newuser:newgroup /to]

Comment: Using shell in this case is not the preferable way since you are losing idempotency. You should instead use file module and with_items

Comment: yes, i'd like to use the file module, but with_items does not support globs does it? listing every file in a with_items list is not really what I want

Comment: See my answer, there is what you need

Comment: How is *shell: chown* **not** idempotent? You can run it as many times as you like, and the state of the machine is exactly the same as if you'd just run it once. That's [idempotency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence), no?

Comment: Every time you run chown, you change file's timestamp. In particular ctime. That might be issue for some backup software for example.

Comment: The link is now broken. I suspect this would be an alternative: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_lookups.html.

Answer (score 5):

Ansible 1.1 added the recurse parameter to the file module, so all you need to do for your change ownership task is this:

```
- name: change ownership 
  action: file state=directory recurse=yes path=/to/ owner=newuser group=newgroup
```

This will make it more apparent when actually things change; using the shell or command modules will always return a changed status, even if nothing was actually changed.